# How to insert multiple records in tableA based on tableB records row?

Tags: mysql, insert, sql-insert

I have Table A and Table B as below:-

**Table A**

```
user_id|sub_category_id|category_id|is_removed
5      |201            |2          |false
```

**Table B**

```
sub_category_id|category_id
101            |1
102            |1
103            |1
201            |2
```

May I know how to insert multiple records into Table A base on Table B if Category_id is 1 with user_id is 5 and is_removed is false?
Thank you.

Comment: Can you show your expected output?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Short answer:**

given the two tables described:

```
insert into A (select 5, sub_category_id, category_id, false from B where category_id = 1);
```

**Detailed explanation:**

A content:

```
select * from A;
+---------+-----------------+-------------+------------+
| user_id | sub_category_id | category_id | is_removed |
+---------+-----------------+-------------+------------+
|       5 |             201 |           2 |          0 |
+---------+-----------------+-------------+------------+
```

B content:

```
select * from B;
+-----------------+-------------+
| sub_category_id | category_id |
+-----------------+-------------+
|             101 |           1 |
|             102 |           1 |
|             103 |           1 |
|             201 |           2 |
+-----------------+-------------+
```

Create a view:

```
select 5, sub_category_id, category_id, false from B where category_id = 1;
+---+-----------------+-------------+-------+
| 5 | sub_category_id | category_id | FALSE |
+---+-----------------+-------------+-------+
| 5 |             101 |           1 |     0 |
| 5 |             102 |           1 |     0 |
| 5 |             103 |           1 |     0 |
+---+-----------------+-------------+-------+
```

Insertion:

```
insert into A (select 5, sub_category_id, category_id, false from B where category_id = 1);
+---------+-----------------+-------------+------------+
| user_id | sub_category_id | category_id | is_removed |
+---------+-----------------+-------------+------------+
|       5 |             201 |           2 |          0 |
|       5 |             101 |           1 |          0 |
|       5 |             102 |           1 |          0 |
|       5 |             103 |           1 |          0 |
+---------+-----------------+-------------+------------+
```